# ImportError: No module named naive_bayes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-2.x

I just installed sklearn, my program runs no problem when I import it into the code.  However, whenever I try to access the `naive_bayes` module, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named naive_bayes
```

Here's how I'm importing it:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell us how you've installed scikit-learn, and your version of sklearn (`import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)`) and python distribution? Installing using `pip install scikit-learn` and importing using `from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB` works ok for me.

Comment: @charlesreid1  Installed in the same manner, I've got python version 2.7.  Trying to run it in PyCharm, no luck.

Comment: Please include output of `import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)` command in your post.

Comment: Was able to install numpy and implement it no problem.  Also the autocomplete functions are popping up when I access instances of GaussianNB, yet for whatever reason it's not recognizing the library.

Comment: "Module has no attribute '__version__"

Comment: Huh. What about `import sklearn; print(sklearn.__file__)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit of "turn it off, and turn it back on again" solutions, and given the fact that you're getting a `Module has no attribute: __version__` when you try and print the scikit-learn version (which should be defined in any self-respecting Python module), I'm going to recommend you uninstall and reinstall scikit-learn:

```
pip uninstall sklearn
pip install sklearn
```

Run the following commands, and compare to the output provided, to make sure the package is behaving the way it should:

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> print(sklearn.__version__)
0.19.0
>>> print(sklearn.__file__)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py
>>>
```

The output from printing `sklearn.__file__` does not need to match exactly, but it should at least print *some* location on your computer.

Also, check to make sure your `pip` matches your `python`. This depends on what platform you're on, but this mix of version 2 and version 3 sometimes creates a nasty cocktail. Executing `pip --version` should tell you which version of Python it is tied to.

```
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3

$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

You should be OK with Python version 2, so long as things match.

(Soap box moment: move to Python 3 if you don't have a really good reason for sticking with Python 2!)

Comment: Did everything you said, tried typing my code directly into the terminal with python and everything worked no problem.  However, when I run the same code in Pycharm, I'm still getting that error message.

Comment: What are the results of running `import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__); print(sklearn.__file__)` in PyCharm? Is it the same as when you run it in Python started from the command line?

Comment: Second question: what is the output of `which python` (from command line), and is it the same as the Python interpreter used by PyCharm? (PyCharm > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console, look in the "Python Interpreter" text box.) If they do not match, change the PyCharm Python Interpreter to match the output of the `which python` command and give it another whirl.

Comment: When I try to import sklearn into the terminal of PyCharm, I get "ImportError: No module named naive_bayes."  Did the version check on python, it's 2.7.10.  Looked in my python interpreter, it too has python 2.7.10.

Comment: I will point out that the original question was answered (above: "Did everything you said, tried typing my code directly into the terminal with python and everything worked no problem")) and this is evolving into a different question. I suggest you accept an answer and start a new question **that is specifically about the PyCharm issue.** Otherwise this comments thread will get excessive.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while installing sklearn and scikit-learn through pip.

**I fixed the issue through the following steps**

1. pip uninstall sklearn (if already installed)
2. pip uninstall scikit-learn( if already installed)
3. git clone [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git)
4. cd scikit-learn
5. python setup.py install

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That works for me
Maybe you need to install Cython as prerequisite 
"pip install cython"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the sklearn installation does not include the naive_bayes in your installation. If the sklearn install correctly, it would say something like

```
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.naive_bayes2'
```

However, in your  case, the import error shows a bit different output. Please check the version and run the test file.

Comment: The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html) states that it should be imported as `from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB`